# Is there a way to add a search option to the multi-select or select widgets in bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I am using the select widget in bokeh to interactively select the columns to plot. The number of columns for my use case is very large (>500 columns). So instead of scrolling through all column names to select the right column for the plot, is there a way to attach a simple search box for user input and based on that input, to filter out the 500 columns to say a much smaller number - making it easier to select the column.

Comment: With the Select widget, after clicking on it, you can type with your keyboard and it will go to the closest match. So if you use a sorted list of options this is a start

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do it in the `Select` itself. You either have to create another widget yourself or use a separate text input field where you could enter some filter. An example:

```
import random
import string

from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models import Select, TextInput, ColumnDataSource, CustomJS


def random_str():
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(20))


ds = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(options=[random_str() for _ in range(500)]))
# Setting initial values
s = Select(options=ds.data['options'])
ti = TextInput(placeholder='Enter filter',
               callback=CustomJS(args=dict(ds=ds, s=s),
                                 code="s.options = ds.data['options'].filter(i => i.includes(cb_obj.value));"))

show(widgetbox(ti, s))
```

The example doesn't require `bokeh serve` - it does all the filtering in your browser. Note that `TextInput` calls its callback only when a user either unfocuses the widget or presses Enter.

Comment: Eugene, thank you! that works perfectly :) Appreciate your help

Comment: This is cool, thanks. I have 2 notes:
1. the code has to be updated for the recent bokeh versions (widgetbox is being deprecated and callback parameter for TextInput is not there anymore)
2. It would be great if we could attach the handler to keyup event through bokeh...